# import data into a specific column in HANA table

Tags: database, csv, hana

I have loaded data into HANA using a CSV file and now I have added a new column to the table by

`ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD (<columnname> <datatype>);`

Now I want to import data into this specific column using a CSV file. I could not find any methods to import to a specific column. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV import feature doesn't allow for partial loading and "column filling".
What you could do is to load the new data (together with the key columns of course) to a staging table and then update the target table columns from there.

Be aware that the CSV import is **not meant** to be an ETL solution. For that, the smart data integration features are there.

Comment: Is it possible to insert all the array elements into one table at once?

Comment: Not sure what "array"  you are referring here to. To insert/update values in ARRAY typed columns, you have to use the ARRAY ( ... ,... ,...) operator.

Comment: Yes I know that I have to use the ARRAY (..,...,...) operator.But my question is that how to insert a large number of entries into the table?For example I have 10 million rows(arrays) in a file.So how can I insert those values into the array column?

Comment: Ok, 1) in your orig. question there was nothing about arrays. 2) There is no built in bulk loading for ARRAY data types available, since the current implementation exlusively support ARRAYS for HANA Internal processing/storage. To load a lot of records with ARRAYS you'll have to create the INSERT statements in a loop, specifyingt each array individually.
Out of curiosity: how does the source data look like exactly?

Comment: Thank you clarifying.The source data is an array column which look likes  {1,2,3..},{2,3,4...},{6,7,8,9...},............